# curl (works) vs HttpURLConnection (fails) under Android

Tags: android, curl, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to convert curl calls into Http, but no matter what options I use, the response code is always 400. Here are the related code snippets. Would appreciate if folks can point what I'm missing here:

```
// Java side    
url = new URL(myUrl);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");  
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Charset", "UTF-8");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.connect();

DataOutputStream writer = new 
DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
writer.writeBytes(buf);
writer.flush();
writer.close();

int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
Log.w(TAG, "responseCode = " +responseCode);   // Always 400

// Native side
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, myUrl);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, buf);

curl_mem_t apiTokenKey;
memset(&apiTokenKey, 0, sizeof(curl_mem_t));
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_mem_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *) &apiTokenKey);

rc = curl_easy_perform(curl);
printf("rc = %d\n", rc); // Always 0
```

Comment: Is your URL string properly encoded? (By, for example, replacing spaces by '%20')?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I actually don't have any spaces in the URL. I just printed the stack trace & it's throwing a java.io.FileNotFoundException. Does that mean the URL is invalid?

Comment: I think you should point the line where the exception is thrown and possibly the  stack trace

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found that the issue was I had to use the right set of properties